# Scala: List of Future of Map

Tags: scala, dictionary, future

I have a list which contains Future of Map

```
val m1 = Future(Map(("A" -> 1), ("B" -> 1)))

val m2 = Future(Map(("A" -> 1), ("C" -> 1)))

val m3 = Future(Map(("C" -> 5), ("D" -> 1)))

val list = List(m1, m2, m3)
```

I want to merge all the Map and aggregate the value of key. I want the output as below

`Future(Map(A -> 2, B -> 1, C -> 6, D -> 1)`

How can I perform the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Future.sequence` method to perform transformation from `List[Future[Map[_, _]]]` to `Future[List[Map[_, _]]]` and then merge maps using reduce function on the list and passing your custom merge function to it.

The example:

```
val list = List(m1, m2, m3)

def merge(first: Map[String, Int], second: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Int] = {
  first ++ second.map { case (k, v) => (k, v + first.getOrElse(k, 0)) }
}

Future.sequence(list).map(_.reduce(merge _)) // will produce Future(Map(A -> 2, B -> 1, C -> 6, D -> 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
val m1 = Future(Map(("A" -> 1), ("B" -> 1)))
val m2 = Future(Map(("A" -> 1), ("C" -> 1)))
val m3 = Future(Map(("C" -> 5), ("D" -> 1)))

val futures = List(m1, m2, m3) 
val future = Future.sequence(futures) // Converts List of Future to Future of List
val futureMap = future.map(_.flatMap(_.toList).toMap)
```

Basically this converts, `Seq[Map[String, Int]]` into first `Seq[(String, Int)]` and then finally convert it to Map: `Map[String, Int]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    val m1 = Future(Map('A'->1, 'B'->1))
    val m2 = Future(Map('A'->1, 'B'->1))
    val m3 = Future(Map('A'->1, 'B'->1))
    val m4 = Future(Map('A'->1, 'C'->1))

## here group all Future[Map[Char,Int]]] into a Future[List[(Char, Int)]] ##

    val myData= for {
      x1 <- m1
      x2 <- m2
      x3 <- m3
      x4 <- m4
    } yield (x1.toList++x2.toList++x3.toList++x4.toList)
```

// Iterate Future[List[(Char, Int)]] and group by key [char], sum it's values

```
    val groupedData =  myData.map(x =>  x.groupBy(_._1).map{
        case (k,v) => k -> v.map(_._2).sum
      } )

    groupedData.foreach(println)
```